# ggplot: showing custom legend with multiple layers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot with several layers of bars and points. I could not figure out how to correctly show the legend for each layer. Here is the code:

```
country <- c(rep(c("AA"), 4), rep(c("BB"), 4))
score <- c(1.3, 7.2, 4.9, 7.5, 6.8, 4.1, 4.9, 5.8)
y_axis <- c(rep(c("Score 2019", "Score 2020", "Group median", "Cluster average"), 2))

dt <- data.table(country, score, y_axis)


ggplot(, aes(country, score)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_bar(data=dt[y_axis=="Score 2019"], stat="identity", fill="grey", width=0.5) +
  geom_point(data=dt[y_axis=="Score 2020"], aes(shape="Score 2020"), color="green4", size=2) +
  geom_point(data=dt[y_axis=="Cluster average"], aes(shape="Cluster average"), color="orange", size=2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=unique(dt[y_axis=="Group median"][,score]), size=1, color="red3")
```

Right now I only manage to have "Cluster average" and "Score 2020" to show up in the legend (with wrong colors). How can I correctly display all layers in the legend (score 2019 and 2020, median and average)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the legend to appear for the points correctly, you need to map the colors *and* shapes to aesthetics. Keep the `hline` separate and map it to a different, non-consequential aesthetic such as `linetype` to get it to appear on the legend.

```r
ggplot(, aes(country, score)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  geom_col(data = dt[y_axis == "Score 2019"], 
           aes(fill = "Score"), width = 0.5) +
  geom_point(data = dt[y_axis == "Score 2020"], 
             aes(shape = "Score 2020", color = "Score 2020"), size = 4) +
  geom_point(data = dt[y_axis == "Cluster average"], size = 4,
             aes(shape="Cluster average", color = "Cluster average")) +
  geom_hline(data =  dt[y_axis == "Group median"],
             aes(yintercept = score, linetype = "Group median"), 
             color = "red4", size = 1) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Cluster average" = 16,
                                "Score 2020" = 17), name = "Legend") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Cluster average" = 'orange', 
                                "Score 2020" = "green4"), name = "Legend") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "gray") +
  labs(linetype = "") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "mm"),
        legend.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! What about the bar?

Comment: Specify the "fill" statement as an aesthetic, e.g. `geom_col(data = dt[y_axis == "Score 2019"], aes(fill = score), width = 0.5)

Comment: @TechCommodities but the bar then turns an awful light red. How do I keep it grey?

Comment: And also, how do I get the different legends to be just a single one, i.e. without all the spacing in between them?

Comment: Specify the colours you want for the bars, using `scale_colour_manual(values = c("grey", "grey")`.  It might be easier to post another question with your new code, asking about uniting the legends.